VBA Looping with multiple variables
I have a worksheet with multiple tabs.  What’s the best method to loop through multiple iterations of variables.  I’m showing the code I have for one iteration and would like to repeat that code multiple times.  I’m showing the declarations for the variables and where they get their data (and also for the 2nd iteration to show it’s different).  Ultimately I’d like to “Loop” through the lines of code between the double sets of  “*************”, and not have to duplicate the code for each iteration.
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Static present1 As Integer
Static copycell1 AS String
Static score1 As Integer
Static points1 As Double
Static best1 As String
Static subtest1 As Integer
Static subplace1 As String


present1 = Range("D9").Value
copycell1 = Range("CK9").Value
score1 = Range("AA9").Value
points1 = Range("AG9").Value
best1 = Range("DZ9").Value
subtest1 = Range("CI11").Value
subplace1 = Range("CK11").Value
' ==========================================================================
'present2 = Range("D13").Value
'copycell2 = Range("CK10").Value
'score2 = Range("AA13").Value
'points2 = Range("AG13").Value
'best2 = Range("DZ10").Value
'subtest2 = Range("CI12").Value
'subplace2 = Range("CK12").Value
' **************************************************************************************
‘ **************************************************************************************
If present1 = "0" Then
    score1 = "xx" & score1
End If
If present1 = "1" Then
    Range(frombest1).Copy
    Worksheets(8).Range(best1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
    Worksheets(7).Activate
    Worksheets(7).Range(copycell1).Value = points1
    Worksheets(7).Range("A1").Select
    If subtest1 = "True" Then
        Copycell1 = Range(subplace1).Value
    End If
End If

Worksheets(6).Activate
Worksheets(6).Range(copycell1).Value = score1
Worksheets(6).Range("A1").Select
‘***************************************************************************************
‘***************************************************************************************
End Sub

I seem to get caught between the variable names and the content of the variables.

This might be easier to understand with some sample data and the expected outcome. You show a whole bunch of variables, but only present1 is in the section of code you say you want to loop. Side note: you want to avoid using Select in your code

You seem to be confusing the value of ranges and the ranges themselves Set myVariable = Range("A1") is not the same as myVariable = Range("A1").Value

Integers (should be Long) , Strings, & Doubles... without more context, not much to be said, considering you can't use the prescribed code for 0 or 1 for the string (technically it can be a numeric string).  Activate/Select are only hurting you... live and let go.

As I stated, I like to loop as many times as I have groupings of  variables, so all variable ending in "1" is one loop, "2" is a second loop, etc.   Looping between the comments with the asterisks.  As for example of data type in the variables:  present1 = 0 or 1, copycell1 = AX1003, score1  = 53, points1 = 16.5, best1 = e1002:m1002, subtest1 = 30, subplace1 =  bb1003.

I tried to declare Static i As Integer and i = 1, then add a "For i = 1 to x, changed all the variables to "name(i)" but that didn't work (not sure why).

"it didn't work" doesn't help us diagnose the problem. I suggest you edit your question to provide sample data, expected result and an explanation of what the macro should be doing and how it fails to achieve that goal.

I can see a pattern where each next value is 1 cell below except for present, score, and points which are 4 cells below. Could you confirm by sharing the 3rd 'set' of variables? How will you determine the value of x mentioned in your previous comment i.e. how many 'sets' there are? Are these first 7 ranges located on Worksheets(6)? Is this code in the workbook containing these sheets? I can't find frombest1 anywhere. What is it and on which sheet is it located? If subtest is 30, how can it ever become "True"? Maybe you mean greater than 0 or not empty?

Ok, let me try this again.  Below is the code that actually works for 2 iterations.  If I want to expand this code to 6 or 8, I do not want to hardcode the code (highlighted in gray) 6 to 8 times.   I'd like to know what changes I need to make this into a LOOP.  For example: What change do I need to make to the declarations, what do I need to add?  What changes do I make to "player 1" code to loop through all the players, then delete the "player 2" code.

I know what you need, no need to repeat yourself. I can't help you without you answering the 6 questions in my previous comment. At least try. Also, you should share some screenshots to make things clearer.

I'm having an issue adding another version of the code in the comments.

ok, 6 answers: yes, all vars on Worksheet 6.  3rd sets of Score, Points, Present & ESC are 4 rows below 2nd set and 8 rows below the 1sr set, 3rd sets of Frombest, Copycell & Best are 8 rows below 1st set.   "X" is meant to be for number of times Looping (so if I expand to 6 or 8 players).  Frombest contain similar data to Best (ex. df9:dx9), my bad for not having it declared at the top.  for subtest, the cell actually is a "true" or "false" testing another cell for data.
